# Sending Parameters to the Function called by a thread in C#?

Tags: c#

Sending Parameters to the Function called by a thread in C#,
this is my code:

```
myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(myfunc));
myThread.Start(i);

public void myfunc(int i)
{
    ...
}
```

I get error:

> No overload for 'installDrivers' matches delegate
>   'system.Threading.ThredStart'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
myThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(myfunc)); 
myThread.Start(i);

public void myfunc(object i) {... }
```

it might be usefull for your issue

Comment: sari - `bool[] arrBool = (bool[])o;` where `o` is the function argument.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [ParameterizedThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx).

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(myfunc));
myThread.Start(i);
```

And your function

```
public void myfunc(object i)
{
    int myInt = Convert.ToInt32(i);
}
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer, but any reason for using `Convert.ToInt32` instead of simple `int myInt = (int)i;`?

Comment: my parameters is array of bool, how can I convert them from object to array of bool?

Answer (score 1):

Another option, utilizing lambdas makes it easy to call functions with any number of parameters, it also avoids the rather nasty conversion from `object` in the one parameter case:

```
int paramA = 1;
string paramB = "foo";

var myThread = new Thread(() => SomeFunc(paramA, paramB));
myThread.Start();

public void SomeFunc(int paramA, string paramB)
{
  // Do something...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using C# < 2.0, you don't need to create a delegate. You can let the compiler implicitly create it for you.

```
myThread = new Thread(myfunc); 
myThread.Start(i);

public void myfunc(object i) 
{
    int i2 = (int)i; // if i is an int
}
```

but note that the `Thread` constructor accepts only two types of delegates: one that is parameterless (`ThreadStart`) and one that accepts an `object` parameter (`ParameterizedThreadStart`). So here we are using the second one.